# Entity Framework 5 One-to-one with named foreign key but using attributes

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Is it possible to accomplish this using just attributes?
I need the Class2 table to have its own primary key of Id and a column called Class2Id that is the foreign key to Class1.Id.

```
public class Class1
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Class2 Class2 { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Class1 Class1 { get; set; }        
}
```

I can get it to work using the fluent mappings using:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>()
  .HasRequired(x => x.Class2)
  .WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Class1)
  .Map(x => x.MapKey("Class1Id"));
```

Comment: This is a good question (and im not too sure of the answer) but just out of interest why dont you want to use the fluent interface to perform this setup. (IMO Fluent > attribute based)

Answer (score 1):

According to "Programming Entity Framework: Code First" book by Julia Lerman, it should be possible. The configuration depends if it is optional 1-1 relationship or required 1-1 relationship.
It is done by using

> [Key]

and

> [ForeignKey]

data annotations applied on dependent end.
The book contains following example:

```
public class PersonPhoto
{
  [Key]
  [ForeignKey("PhotoOf")]
  public int PersonId { get; set; }
  public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
  public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```